# How to pull social icons to the right when using central logo navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

When I pull my social icons to the right, they end up pushing my centered logo down a little, as opposed to being placed at the same height as the logo (i.e not higher than the logo, creating extra white space above it)

I have tried floating them to the left, making the position absolute etc but with no luck.

Could someone please help me out with making them appear at the top right of the screen but without extra space above them?

Here is my code for the navbar with social icons:

html

```
    <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Cars</a></li>
    <a href="#"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="../assets/images/logo.png" width="250" alt="logo"></a>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     </ul>

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i></a>   </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-lg"></i></a></li>
        </ul>



    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->                  
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#navbar-primary .navbar-nav { 
background: #fff;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
li {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
}
}


.social {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

.social ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
}

.social ul li {
margin: 5px;
list-style: none outside none;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Any help much appreciated, I have been stuck on this for a number of days

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to make something like this screenshot? http://imgur.com/a/xpnHn

Comment: Yes, but only with the logo and the nav links all centred

Comment: I had it like the screenshot for another website and that was fine, but for some reason when I want the logo and links centred it seems to put it to the right but above the logo, so it creates extra space if you know what I mean?

Comment: can you give me a screenshot of what you exactly want? it will be easy for me to write the code.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZ8I.png

Comment: Check this one http://imgur.com/a/RPqcd. I just did this

Comment: Thanks that is nearly there! Only the social icons make the distance between the logo and the left and right hand side of the page different, could you put a negative margin in to sort this out or would that not do it? Thanks a lot for helping out

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did, but there might have some responsive issue but it might help you.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <style type="text/css">
                .navbar .navbar-nav {
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: none;
                }

                .navbar .navbar-collapse {
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .top-nav{
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    min-height: 20px;
                }
                .top-nav .navbar-nav>li>a{
                    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
                }
                .top-nav .navbar-right{
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }
                .logo{
                    margin-top: -30px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar top-nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i></a>   </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <nav id="navbar-primary" class="navbar" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-primary-collapse">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-primary-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Our Cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" style="padding-top: 0;"><img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Silver Lining Wedding and Classic Car Chauffeurs Nottingham Logo"></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid --> 
            </nav>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sure I can sort out the responsive issues.. Does this get rid of the extra space between the logo and right hand side when the icons are there? Thanks

Comment: yes. You can directly paste this code to a html file and just add the logo and check.

Comment: And don't forget to click on accept the answer if it really helped you.

Comment: Hey, Very sorry I couldn't get it to work properly :( I will upvote your answer though. I am still trying to figure it out to be honest, I keep messing it up, I think because my css is separate and when I put this in my css files it doesn't work like yours does, i am probably doing something very stupid